# Showing file upload progress with WorkManager

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am uploading files with retrofit multipart.

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload")
    fun uploadFiles(
    @Part file: MultipartBody.Part,
    @Part requestBody: RequestBody,
    ): Call<UploadResult>
```

I start the uploading of files in a worker.

```
         val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<UploadWorker>()
                .setInputData(builder.build())
                .build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(context)
                .enqueue(request)
```

How should I do progress showing? I'm confused about this.
Workmanager also has a progress implementation. Retrofit file upload also has a progress implementation. Which one should I use?